# Get the state variable after dispatch is finished in react redux and saga?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga, redux-reducers

Hello I am fairly new to React, Redux and Saga. So I have a scenario where I have a .jsx file which is the view file then an action file used for dispatch and I am also using saga which updates the data in the reducers. Following are the file structurs:

1. Action file:

```
export const getAction = (requestor) => ({
  type: GET_ACTION,
  data: {
    requestor,
  },
});
```

2. Reducer file

```
export const Reducer = (currentState = {}, action) => {
  const newState = { ...currentState };

  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ACTION:
      newState.data = action.data;
      return newState;
  }  
};
```

3. Saga file

```
function* getData(action) {
  const { requestor } = action.data;
  try {
    const data = yield call(callService);
    if(success) {
      yield put( {type: GET_ACTION, data} );
    }
  } catch (e)
  {
  }
}

function* getDataSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(GET_ACTION, getData);
}

export {
  getData,
};

export default [
  getDataSaga,
];
```

4. jsx file

```
const [dummy, setDummy] = useState([]);
const data = useSelector(state => state.data, shallowEqual) || {};

There is a function in which dispatch function is called.

dispatch(getAction(requestor));
```

Now I need to access the updated state of data after dispatch has finished updating the data because after the data is updated I have to setDummy to set the dummy variable mentioned. Any way which I can be approaching to achieve that. I have tried to use dispatch.then but on UI it is saying .then is not a function for dispatch.

Comment: you're dispatching `GET_ACTION` but not handling it in the reducer, so that action doesn't cause a state change

Comment: actually it was misspelled the case was for GET_ACTION.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> after the data is updated I have to setDummy

`useEffect` lets you do something upon a given prop changing

```
const [dummy, setDummy] = useState([]);
const data = useSelector(state => state.data, shallowEqual) || {};

// setDummy when `data` changes
useEffect(() => {
  setDummy(data);
}, [data])
```